# Does Google Analytics 4 show an exact count of returning users?

Tags: google-analytics

This is in regards to the new Google Analytics 4. While looking for exact numbers on the returning users, there is only one place i observed. It is under Life Cycle -> Retention -> Overview. That says the count as 2.5K. I want to know the exact count, say 2489 or whatever it is.
There isn't detailed documentation found anywhere including google, unless I missed something.

And also is there any easier way to add this Returning Users as a metric to other places (like Page views and screen)?

Comment: Google Analytics almost always uses sampling to estimate totals.   Even if you found an exact count, it isn't going to be an accurate exact count.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds logical.